# Square preview of camera

Tags: android, android-camera

I am try to preview of camera in square something like Instagram app but there is problem preview squeezing, I put a constant value in height and width of layout and same as in preview size. I tried following answers.

[How can I set camera preview size to squared aspect ratio in a squared SurfaceView (like Instagram)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121963/how-can-i-set-camera-preview-size-to-squared-aspect-ratio-in-a-squared-surfacevi)
and
[Custom Square camera - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22321794/custom-square-camera-android)